# What is the pros and cons of different ways of accessing list elements?

Tags: python, loops, iterable

I have question based on looping through iterable objects with a counter.

What is the benefit / advantage of either method below as they do the same thing:

```
list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

 #Method 1

for index in range(len(list)):
    value = list[index]
    print(index, value)



#Method 2 

for index, values in enumerate(list):
    print(index, values)
```

Comment: Personal preference? Use-case dependent?

Comment: Use-case dependent I'd say. There are use cases where keeping track in index might be worthwhile, it just doesn't happen to be the case with your particular use case

Comment: Besides the good comments above ^^^.  Avoid using the builtin *list* as the variable name...

Comment: The prob. description is kind off - there is no *counters* here,  it's about different ways *indexing* / *accessing* the list elements.  Try to revise it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My way of using for loops is:

If you just need the values of a list, just get the values:

```
l = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

for value in l:
   print(l)
```

If you need the index and the value, use enumerate:

```
for index, value in enumerate(l):
   print(index, value)
```

If you need to loop over two lists at the same time, you could use range to get the indexes:

```
l2 = l = ["e", "f", "g", "h"]
for index in range(len(list)):
    print(index, l[index], l2[index])
```

however its more pythonic to use a zip:

```
for val1, val2 in zip(l, l2):
    print(val1, val2)
```

If you want to do something a number of times, rather than looping over an object, use range:

```
n = 10

for i in range(n):
    print(i)
```

However as always, just use whatever is best for your use case and is the most readable.